# Mysql Deadlock on Update with Joins

Tags: mysql, sql-update, deadlock

I'm having some deadlock troubles when this query runs multiple times simultaneously, and hoped somebody could point me in the right direction with how to fix it.

Here's the query:

```
UPDATE MultipleChoiceAnswer mca_copy
INNER JOIN
MultipleChoiceAnswer mca_original
ON mca_original.id = mca_copy.copy_of_multiple_choice_answer_id AND mca_original.id=?
INNER JOIN 
QuizQuestion qq_copy 
ON qq_copy.id = mca_copy.question_id
INNER JOIN 
Section s_copy
ON s_copy.id = qq_copy.section_id AND s_copy.quiz_auto_update=1
SET 
mca_copy.answer=mca_original.answer,
mca_copy.correct=mca_original.correct
```

Basically, when a particular row updates, I need to update some other rows in the same table as well. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: Are the join fields all indexed? Have you checked what innodb status monitor says about the deadlock?

Comment: Hey Shadow, the join fields aren't all indexed, I'll give that a try and see if it makes any difference. If not I'll get into the innodb status monitor and see what that has to say as well :). The deadlock seems to resolve itself pretty quickly, it just kills queries when multiple people try to save something right at the same time (and will probably grow worse and worse)

Comment: If the join fields are not indexed, then innodb will have to do a full table scan to find the matching records, thereby locking most of the tables involved in the join.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure there's a better solution to this, but following Shadow's advice I indexed the columns and can't recreate any deadlocks. I may do some further investigation and let you guys know, but for now the problem is resolved.